# Marshaled struct followed by fixed size data

Tags: c#, c++

I want to pass some data from c# to c++. These data consist of struct and guid. Since guid is class I decided to copy it immediately after struct data. Is there a better way to do this? This solution works and data are read correctly in c++, but I am little worried whether there are cases, when this would not work.

Struct:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
struct TEST_STRUCT
{
    public Uint32 var1;
    public Uint32 var2;
}
```

Use:

```
TEST_STRUCT testStruct = new TEST_STRUCT(); // filled somewhere
byte [] guid; // defined above

IntPtr mem = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(testStruct.GetType()) + guid.Length);
try
{
    Marshal.StructureToPtr(testStruct, mem, false);
    Marshal.Copy(guid, 0, new IntPtr(mem.ToInt64() + Marshal.SizeOf(testStruct.GetType())), guid.Length);

    // send data to c++ ...
}
finally
{
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(mem);
}
```

Comment: You are correct, data were correctly transferred. Can you post it separately so I can mark it as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll get away with it in this very specific case, a GUID does not have an alignment requirement.  The structure is always 24 bytes long.

But there is no point in doing it this way, the pinvoke marshaller knows how to correctly marshal System.Guid.  It is a value type (a struct), not a class as you assumed, and its internal structure is intentionally clunky so it exactly matches a native GUID.  Something you can see from the [Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/guid.cs,b622ef5f6b76c10a) for example.  That was very intentional, Guids are important in interop, COM code in particular uses them heavily.

So all it takes is:

```
struct TEST_STRUCT
{
    public Uint32 var1;
    public Uint32 var2;
    public Guid guid;
}
```

I intentionally left out the [StructLayout] attribute, it is not necessary and packing does not have to be tweaked.